# Scrollbar not showing up in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I'm trying to put a scrolling text area, called descriptionScroll. However, the scroll bar is NOT visible. I've tried many approaches, and all end in frustration.

Am I missing anything to get the scroll bar showing? It should appear to the right of the large text box next to "Description"

Here's the **relevant** piece of code:

```
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

protected JTextArea descriptionTextArea;


protected JScrollPane descriptionScroll;


String descriptionText = 
"Lot ID(s):\n" +
"Wafer ID(s):\n" +
"PSPT(Probe Ship Part Type):\n" +
"Tester:\n" +
"Tester Job Name:\n" +
"PID (FPP, FPC):\n" +
"Reprobe required before shipping lot? (Y/N)\n\n" +
"Hold for (individual):\n" +
"Hold for (group)\n" +
"Expected release date\n" +
"Hold Comments:\n\n" +
"Shipping Information:\n" +
"Special Instructions:\n";


public Constructor(){

descriptionTextArea = new JTextArea(descriptionText);
descriptionScroll = new JScrollPane(descriptionTextArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
add(descriptionTextArea);
add(descriptionScroll);  
pack();

setSize(790, 625);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setVisible(true);


descriptionTextArea.setSize(650, 200);
descriptionTextArea.setLocation(110, 228);
descriptionTextArea.setLineWrap(true);



}
```

[image: Missing scroll]

Comment: Simply remove the line `add(descriptionTextArea);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding both JScrollPane and JTextArea to the same container. Add the JTextArea to JScrollPane:

`descriptionScroll.add(descriptionTextArea);`

Comment: Sorry. You need not to add() JTextArea to JScrollPane. You need to set it as viewportView. descriptionScroll.setViewportView(descriptionTextArea);

Comment: Please fix your post. `descriptionScroll.add(descriptionTextArea);` will not work. `setViewPortView` or using JScrollpane constructor is the way to go.

Comment: I tried removing the line add(descriptionTextArea).. but now the text box disappeared. I need the scrollbar to scroll up & down descriptionTextArea. I also tried descriptionScroll.setViewportView(descriptionTextArea), to no avail. Why is this so complicated?

Comment: Set the location and size of the JScrollPane instead of the JTextArea.